# Angular - If checkbox is checked hide div

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

Im trying to hide some div if the checkbox is checked. When the box is checked is adds the md-checked class so i need to see if that is true and then hide the class notifications, is this the right approach ? Thank you

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="center center" layout-margin layout-fill class="confirm">
  <md-checkbox ng-if="md-checked ? true :  ????? " ng-model="" aria-label="">
  </md-checkbox>
  <a href="#" class="checkbox_alert"></a>
</div>

<div class="notification">
    <lib-notification text="{{error}}" type="danger" ng-if="error">
    </lib-notification>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use the [tag:angularjs-material] tag. The [tag:angular-material] tag is not meant for AngularJS questions.

Comment: Ok , Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the ng-model for your checkbox and use it to determine if you should show the div

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCheckbox" aria-label="">
<div ng-hide="myCheckbox">Hide when checked!</div>
```